# Issues with Sscanf

Tags: c++, c, scanf, c-strings

I decided to use sscanf as a simpler way to parse a string in C++. Here is a sample of my code

```
int x,y,level;
char type;
char *line=NULL;

if(inputMode=='M'){

    while(cin.getline(line,200)){
        sscanf(line,"(%d,%d,%d,%c)",x,y,level,type);
    }
}
```

The format I'm trying to extract from looks like this. I need to extract the three decimal values and the char value and every line of the file I read from will have the same format. I created a c-string called char line[200]. I just chose 200 as an arbitrary size since I never know for certain how long the string will be just knowing that when it's tested, the max numbers inside the file could be in the millions.

```
(3,2,1,#)
```

I get an error saying %d expects an int *. So I thought changing x,y,level, and type to pointers would solve this issue but then the compiler says x,y,level, and type may be uninitialized in the function. I'm compiling using the latest g++ -Wall -Werror if that helps.

Comment: `sscanf(line,"(%d,%d,%d,%c)",&x,&y,&level,&type);`

Comment: "I decided to use sscanf as a simpler way to parse a string in C++" - that's a **wrong** decision. `sscanf()` is as simple for a beginner as diving at 1000 meters deep for someone who can't swim. In C++, you should not ever use `scanf()` at all, under any circumstance. I even discourage its use in C, because this function is just wrong. It has so many counter-intuitive little quirks that it's hard to get its usage right. In C++, use standard classes (`std::stringstream`, `std::string`) and functions for parsing a string. In C, use `strtok()`, `strchr()`, etc.

Comment: okay thanks, ill look into stringstream since I already have it incorporated

Comment: Also, before posting on Stack Overflow, **read** some beginner teaching material about the language. This is so basic that I don't even understand how **possibly** could you miss this. You clearly didn't study a basic tutorial or book, did you. As currently standing, you don't seem to understand what a pointer even is, why pointers are necessary for `scanf()` and you don't seem to know how pasing arguments to functions works. And that's a serious problem.

Comment: I actually did and the examples I saw, didn't use the & sign

Comment: @JoshHamet If they didn't, then that was either `printf()` (or some variant thereof), or the book/article/tutorial/course you are following is wrong, or you missed the & operators.

Comment: okay I understand, just didn't notice it i guess

Comment: Good idea to check the result of `sscanf()` as in `if(sscanf(line,"(%d,%d,%d,%c)",x,y,level,type)) Success();`.

Answer (score 3):

You missed `&` operator before your variables in `sscanf`.

```
sscanf(line,"(%d,%d,%d,%c)", &x, &y, &level, &type);  
                             ^Notice the & operator.
```

Answer (score 2):

scanf family of functions expect pointers to be given as arguments, because they need to modify the variable, and if you pass a copy, they will modify the copy (thus this is useless).

```
int x,y,level;
char type;
char *line=NULL;

if(inputMode=='M'){

    while(cin.getline(line,200)){
        sscanf(line,"(%d,%d,%d,%c)",&x,&y,&level,&type);
    }
}
```

is what you want to do